# Magento2.3 add custom phtml files to footer

Tags: magento2.3, luma-theme, default.xml

I have a Magento 2.3 website that has a child theme of Luma setup and bootstrap added. What I want is to in the footer is to call in a customfooter.phtml file so I can setup the footer to be a 4col layout.
then under the footer and full page width I am trying to add a new div that would call in a footer-links.phtml file and load right before the closing body tag and outside the page wrapper.

My issue is the default.xml does not see to work even though I recompiled and deployed and cleared cache.

Here is my default.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customfooter" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom/customfooter.phtml" />

    <!--this is use for remove default elements -->
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>

    <referenceBlock name="switcher-store" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
    <!-- Footer Elements Ends -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your template like this :

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customfooter" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom/customfooter.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

OR

You can try this, create a cms block with name custom_footer and call this in your theme layout **YOUR_THEME/layout/default.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-custom-block" after="-">
  <arguments>
      <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom_footer</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: I really need it to be a phtml file that is called in because the phtml file calls in 3 static blocks in a 4 column layout.

Comment: Updated follow steps to create new block.

Comment: See my OP I updated my default.xml and compiled deployed and cleared cache but I don't see my phtml file being loaded?

Comment: You need to add in referenceContainer element. Check updated post.

Answer (score 0):

In **default.xml** file use below code to call custom phtml file in footer

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customfooter" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom/customfooter.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```